# elastic search filtering based on filtering results

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is it possible to filter the documents based on the results of another filter ?

For example if I filter documents on

```
"_source": [ "animalName" ],
{ "term":  { "animalType": "dog" }}
```

How can I filter select all the animals that have the name as a dog ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all animals of type dog having the name **$someName**, try this:

```
{
  "_source: ["animalName", "animalWeight", ...],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [{
        "term": {"animalType": "dog"}
      },{
        "term": {"animalName": $someName}
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

**[Udate]**
You mean something like this?

```
select distinct a2.*
from animals a1
  join animals a2 on a1.name = a2.name
where 1
  and a1.type = 'dog'
  and a2.type != 'dog'
```

I don't know how to achieve this in elastic, as 'SQL-style joins' are 'prohibitively expensive' [[1]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html).

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I want ANY animal whose name is shared with a dog.

Comment: Yes that kind of thing